# Size of files and directories on mac via terminal differs from actual size

Tags: bash, macos, size, du

On a mac I want to calculate the size of a folder:

`ls -la` produces the following output:

```
PC:aggregations user$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 user  staff   136 Dec  6 14:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 user  staff   782 Dec  6 11:29 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff  1954 Dec  6 14:33 test_agg_1.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff  1954 Dec  4 11:00 test_agg_2.csv
```

Why the size of current directory `(.)` is 136 bytes only while csv files sum up to `~4000` bytes ?

Moreover, `du -s` produces:

```
PC:aggregations user$ du -s *
8   test_agg_1.csv
8   test_agg_2.csv
PC:aggregations user$ du -s
16  .
```

Can someone give an explanation and suggest how may I calculate the actual size of a directory?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-c` flag in `du` for a grand total.

According to the `man du` page,

```
-c      Display a grand total.
```

So, assuming the below contents in my current folder.

```
dudeOnMac:myScripts freddy$ du -ch .
  0B    ./a
4.9M    ./abcd
4.0K    ./b
  0B    ./hello-images/first-black
  0B    ./hello-images/second-atlas
  0B    ./hello-images
  0B    ./temp/a
  0B    ./temp/b
4.0K    ./temp
5.0M    .
5.0M    total
```

To get the grand sum alone.

```
dudeOnMac:myScripts freddy$ du -ch . | tail -1
5.0M    total
```

Tested on MacOS.

Comment: nxthor has right, `ls -lah` produce different result from `du`. How to calculate grand total from `ls` command?

Comment: after some research I figure out that: ```ls``` is reporting the actual size of the file, whereas ```du``` is reporting the allocation of space for that file, even though it may not be using it.

Comment: Thanks! what i was looking for megabyte sizing and sorted with one item depth.  `du -cmd 1 | sort -g $1`

Comment: @BrandonMorrison: If you'd liked the answer, consider leaving a vote up to the answer

Answer (score 1):

> du(1) - Linux man page
>
> Name
>
> du - estimate file space usage
>
> ...
>
> Description
>
> Summarize disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories.

I think 'du' looks at 'size on disk' instead of real size after loading into memory.

With a blocksize of 8kb as Quantum, the result of 'du' would make sense im comparioson of the first one ('ls -la').

Comment: nah, I missed to tell you ho it is done :)... se that other answer for that (-s Option)